# String replace in substring

Tags: java, xml, regex

I want to write a method for a Java class. The method accepts as input a string of XML data as given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library>

    <book>
        <name> <> Programming in ANSI C <> </name>
        <author> <>  Balaguruswamy <> </author>
        <comment> <> This comment may contain xml entities such as &, < and >. <> </comment>
    </book>

    <book>
        <name> <> A Mathematical Theory of Communication <> </name>
        <author> <> Claude E. Shannon <> </author>
        <comment> <> This comment also may contain xml entities. <> </comment>
    </book>

    <!-- This library contains more than ten thousand books. -->
</library>
```

The XML string contains a lot of substring starting and ending with **<>**. The substring may contain XML entities such as **>**, **<**, **&**, **'** and **"**. The method need to replace them with **&gt;**, **&lt;**, **&amp;**. **&apos;** and **&quot;** respectively.

Is there any regular-expression method in Java to accomplish this task?

Comment: Are you asking to escape all XML, or just the <> that happens in between tags?

Comment: Who is generating the XML? It would seem that the correct way to fix the problem would be to output valid xml as opposed to tinkering with the contents.

Comment: The substring is taken from database. Since the XML string may contain more than thirty thousand substrings, it will be inefficient to escape all XML entities before adding to the XML string. That is why we just introduce the <> and the method is responsible for escaping the XML entities before using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this data being passed to you, or can you control it? If so, then I would suggest using a [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) block. If you are really unsure about the data being entered into the xml blocks, then just wrap everything in a CDATA before it is saved to the DB

If you do not have control over this, then as far as I know, this will take a fair amount of coding due to the number of edge cases you possibly will have to deal with. Not something that a simple regex will be able to deal with (if a valid block is starting, if one is ending, if one has already ended, etc)

Here is a very basic regex for the <> case, but the rest I really believe just get extremely complicated

```
\<\>* //For <> changes
```

Comment: Wow! I think it is a new idea to me. This is not what I try to follow. I think it will work for me. I should replace all the "<>" before the substring with "<![CDATA[" and should replace all the "<>" after the substring "]]>", right?

Comment: Sorry for the earlier delete, I was being distracted and misread a comment of yours, so figured I would rewrite my answer differently later. I have updated it and will give some valid regexes shortly :) But, if you can save the data with CDATA blocks, that will make life easier :D

Answer (score 2):

You can follow  in [an example](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152)

1. Read a XML file by Dom or SAX
2. Replace string by Regular expression
3. Write a XML file by Dom or SAX

Comment: Since the substring contain XML entities, reading Dom will be fail, right?

Comment: I'm not sure; please try it and let me know the result. Thanks